# elasticsearch hightlight query for all field

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to highlight my search text for all searchable field.

I used [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#plain-highlighter) for help.
highlight is not working, query get the normal result without any highlight.
the query didn't get the highlight, what wrong with my query?

**my elastisearch version "5.5.2"**.

**_mapping of index is**:-

```
{
  "products": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**my elasticsearch query is**:-

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "match": { "_all": "rock clamb" }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
        "fields" : {
          "_all" : {}
        }
    }
}'
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 6,
    "failed" : 0
  },
"hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.99835247,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "product",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.99835247,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Push Clamb Car Holder for Samsung and iPhone",
          "price" : 3,
          "description" : "A high quality car holder for smartphones that features a push clamp function Features: Universal car holder Height adjustment pivot Ball shape 360"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "product",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 0.7741236,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 1,
          "description" : "This item fits directly to all 3 power boxes (7850 7880 7890)Together in use these clamps are bi-polarEach individual clamb is uni-polar cable include",
          "title" : "Rimba Luxurous Electrosex clamps Uni-polar (2 pcs) - Naughty"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform highlighting, the actual content of the field is required. If the field in question is stored (has store set to true in the mapping) it will be used, otherwise, the actual _source will be loaded and the relevant field will be extracted from it.

The _all field cannot be extracted from _source, so it can only be used for highlighting if it mapped to have store set to true. Refer link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#plain-highlighter